# how to load groups in listView using Facebook SDK C#

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-like

I am using Facebook SDK c# to make windows application.
I try to load all page which I like it is successful.

The problem is when I press the load page button it load this data 1 more to become have duplicate, and get every page I like it 2 times 
my code

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[,] friends;
        FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(AppSettings.Default.AccessToken);
        dynamic Grouplist = fb.Get("/me/likes");
        int count = (int)Grouplist.data.Count;
        friends = new string[count, 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            listView3.Items.Add(Grouplist.data[i].name);
        }
    }
```

[image]

---

Answer (score 0):

```
listView3.Items.Clear();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    listView3.Items.Add(Grouplist.data[i].name);
}
```